# SQL query- How does the following work?

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: Tables]

Ques: Find The names of all salespeople that have an order with Samsonic.

```
SELECT salesperson.ID FROM test.salesperson
where salesperson.ID IN (Select salesperson.ID from test.orders 
                        inner join test.customer 
                        ON customer.ID = orders.cust_id
                        AND customer.CustName = "Samsonic");
```

I want to know how does the above query works?
It lists all the IDs in the salesperson table.

The confusion is it should either select only those salesperson IDs which are there in orders table (as I am selecting it from orders table : Select salesperson.ID from test.orders) or it should throw an error as there is no coloumn named ID in orders table.

Note : I am using MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is on this line:

```
where salesperson.ID IN (Select salesperson.ID from test.orders
```

You're just getting the ID from the `salesperson` table again. It should probably be:

```
where salesperson.ID IN (Select salesperson_id from test.orders
```

(With `salesperson_id` being the column on `orders`)

Comment: Agreed. But my confusion is when I am giving the table name as ORDERS in the from clause(of subquery) then the subquery should work on the orders table only and since there is no column called ID in orders table it should show an error. Why it is taking the IDs from salesperson table?

Comment: Because you are referring to it with the `salesperson` table name from the initial `FROM` clause. With this table as part of the subquery's select, it doesn't even look at `ORDERS` in this case, just comparing `salesperson.id` with `salesperson.id` which is always true of course, so it simply returns whatever you select. You could specify anything and you would just get a row for each row in `salesperson`. e.g. `select 'test' from salesperson where id in (select salesperson.id from orders)`.

Comment: So do you mean to say that 'from' part of inner query is not actually checked?

Comment: It's checked in the boolean sense. If you had `where number = -999` that would return an empty set and you wouldn't get any results. As long as this clause returns any non-zero result, though, you will get a row for each in `salesperson`. So `(select salesperson.id <any "truth-y" clause>)` becomes equivalent to `(select salesperson.id)` which, as noted, returns a row for each `salesperson`.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of mistakes with your query. `salesperson.ID` should be `salesperson_id` (which will already told). Other than that, there is no `cust_name`. It should just be `customer.name`.

Now if you just want `salesperson id` then no use for outer select. This should work.

```
Select salesperson_ID from test.orders 
             inner join test.customer 
             ON customer.ID = orders.cust_id
             AND customer.Name = "Samsonic"
```

But if you need customer name and/or other details from customer, then use your corrected query.

```
SELECT salesperson.ID, salesperson.name FROM test.salesperson
where salesperson.ID IN (Select salesperson_ID from test.orders 
                    inner join test.customer 
                    ON customer.ID = orders.cust_id
                    AND customer.Name = "Samsonic");
```

Comment: I agree with that but the confusion is when I am giving the table name as ORDERS in the from clause(of subquery) then the subquery should work on the orders table only and since there is no column called ID in orders table it should show an error. Why it is taking the IDs from salesperson table?

Comment: To understand that, please google `correlated subquery`. That is the reason that your query will not return any error.

If you want to test it further, please create a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) with some data.